# I can't see the three vertical dots in my emulator action bar on my device

Tags: java, android

when i see my activity_main.xml layout in android studio it shows the three dotted vertical menu [in android studio](https://i.stack.imgur.com/4TaPe.png) but when i launch my app in my android device there is no vertical dotted[in my android device](https://i.stack.imgur.com/VFO7K.png).

Comment: What API level is your device?

Comment: Android 4.3 & API 18

Answer (score 2):

Changing **showAsAction** attribute to **ifRoom|withText** might help you.

Example:

```
<menu xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android" >

<item
    android:id="@+id/action_settings"
    android:showAsAction="ifRoom|withText"
    android:title="@string/settings"/>

</menu>
```